# CFAbsoluteTime get time components

Tags: c++, objective-c, time

I am using CFAbsoluteTime for storing absolute time value and for conversion to string. Is there any method or way to retrieve the individual time components like year, month, day, hour, min, sec from CFAbsoluteTime without parsing the converted string ?

Comment: You are keeping timeStamp. So convert it to `Date` (with `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)`), and then since you have a `Date`, you can use `DateComponents`, `Calendar` (with `component(_:from:)` for instance), etc to get what you want.

Comment: In that case I may convert this to CFDateRef which can then be used to get the time components.